# How to get Virtual Box VM's running on separate computers to communicate over the LAN?

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, lan

For the last two days I've been trying to make a Hadoop cluster. All I want to do is make the two Lubuntu VM's that I have running (each one on a separate computer) able to speak to each other so one can be a Master node and the other be a Slave node for map-reduce.

I've tried bridged mode, I've tried bridged mode + host only, and a bunch of different things in between. I'm just real lost now. I managed to get them to have static IP's by modifying some net file (forgot the name of it, netapply or something) but I can't get them to communicate over SSH.

The things I read had me thinking to set VirtualBox's host-only DHCP to match the settings on my router's DHCP. But I'm starting to think I must have that wrong.

Can someone explain to me the best way to go about this please? It seems like no one has ever done this before because I can't find a decent guide for this.

Comment: Your physical host PCs are full members of the router's network.  if you configure both VMs to USURP the PCs network presence, then configuring them to accept DHCP straight from the router should get you whatever level of networking you currently enjoy between the physical hosts.  Three issues already: First, the VMs will take over your PC's network device.  Second, you'll have to configure the VMs to match whatever the router currently expects from the PC.  Third, the current setup on the router may not be what you want.  Caveat -- I gave up VBox due to DOS networking issues. Life is short.

Comment: If you put them both on "bridged" mode and both are bridged to the same network then they should just be like physical machines on your LAN

Answer (score 0):

In order for two hosts to communicate, there has to be a route between them.  This can be the "yeah whatever" route of `0.0.0.0` for machines on the same subnet, or via a default gateway, or via a specific gateway to a specific network.

With VirtualBox, you have a few basic networking types.  NAT and NAT Network are fairly similar, in that the VM is on a subnet that your host machine doesn't even see, but traffic out is routed through that host.  You can get your host to communicate with the VMs by forwarding specific ports in the VBox Settings but it is somewhat a pain.

Internal Only is just that, and the VMs can see each other but not the host and the host can't see them.  There is no DHCP service either, so you need to either manage IPs on your own or set up something for DCHP.

Host Only is like Internal Only, but the host machine will get a virtual NIC as well that is on the same internal side network.  If you go with this option, the host machine can be configured to route in one or both directions for the internal network to have LAN and internet access.

Bridged Network is what you want.  With Bridged, you specify a physical adapter on the host machine, and the VMs adapter is "attached" to that.  That means it will be on the same subnet as your LAN, should get DHCP from whatever is doing that, etc.  Note that some managed networks (think schools and corporations) block multiple MACs on a single switch port and will disconnect you.

So... to do what you want.  If the two physical hosts can communicate with each other, and you aren't on a LAN that is blocking the second/third/etc MACs on a single port, you are good to go.  Simply put each VM on a Bridged connection on the host, bridging to the physical adapter on the host that is connected to the LAN.

Comment: Ok but that didn't work. I appreciate what you told me but most that I figured out from reading the guides. The problem is when I try to ssh with the other computer, nothing happens.  It just doesn't connect to anything. I thought bridge mode wasn't working because it was just going to the host pc and not getting to the vm maybe? I 've never used ssh before so its hard for me to understand the problem if I'm following the instructions in a guide to the letter, and then it just doesn't work. Seemed they couldn't communicate. and my router is set to allow the host to host